# Writing a function in two different ways: one way results in a TypeError and the other does not. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, typeerror

I've come across an issue I don't understand what's going on. Here's the setup: the user enters the screen and inputs a last name. I take the last name and search a phone book (the entire phone book has been retrieved when the user enters the screen so it's just sitting there as a big, fat JavaScript array).

Let's assume each element of the phone book object consists of: a last name, first name and phone number. Now, I'll take the last name inputted by the user and loop across the phone book looking for the last names that match. I'll then push each matching element into an array and display that array to the user.

I've written the method to do this in two different ways. In the first way it returns the list of objects. In the second way (my preference), a TypeError is thrown.

Here is the first approach

```
$scope.getMatchingLastNames = function(){
for(i=0; i<$scope.phoneBook.length; i++){
    if($scope.lastName==$scope.phoneBook[i].lastName){
          $scope.filteredArray.push($scope.phoneBook[i]);  
    }
};
```

The second approach:

```
$scope.getList = function(){
    $scope.filteredArray = getLastNames($scope.lastName, 
       $scope.phoneBook, $scope.phoneBook.length);
}
```

Which calls

```
function getLastNames(lastName, phoneBook, length)
{
    var filteredArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(lastName==phoneBook[i].lastName){
            filteredArray.push(phoneBook[i]);  
        }
    }
    return filteredArray;
}
```

When I run the second approach I'll get an error in Chrome console as follows:

```
TypeError:  Cannot read property 'lastName' of undefined
```

And the error points to the if condition:

```
if(lastName==phoneBook[i].lastName)
```

Can someone explain to me why the second approach is resulting in an error?

Thanks.

Comment: note that parser would load/pase-bodies of fns declared like so `function getLastNames` first ... then runetime would threat `var x = function()..` like valiables and bodies would get pasred as in runetime

Comment: what changes if u rewrite `function getLastNames(lastName, phoneBook, length)` in `getLastNames = function(lastName, phoneBook, length)` such manner ?

Comment: @animaacija: Thanks. I'll look into the javascript interpreter. I don't know a lot about how it works so that might be a good first step. To answer your second question: I'm refactoring the code because the other developer ended up adding $scope to a lot of variables so I'm trying to minimize clean up the code. For example, the first method has a $scope.phoneBook but that is never bound to anything in the view.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the error message correctly? It would make more sense if it said **Cannot read property 'lastName' of undefined**

Comment: Are you missing a closing curly brace?

Comment: Are you missing `var` before your `i` in the for loop?

Comment: @barmar and twsaef: Yes. You're both correct. I was writing the post from memory and was sloppy. I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possibly you have another copying error, like the actual code has `i <= length` instead of `i < length`? The error means that `phoneBook[i]` is undefined, and there's nothing in the code you posted that would explain why this only happens when you use the function instead of the inline loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are trying to achieve is to filter a list of results, I suggest you use angularJs filters

I prepared a jsfiddle for you with a simple example:
https://jsfiddle.net/fb0r7z0q/

This is the key line:

```
<li ng-repeat="entry in phonebook | filter:qname">
```

qname being your $scope.lastName